# How to Retrieve a webpage in Android app using native code?

Tags: android, native

I am trying to build a native app for my website,i wanna know how can i retrieve the contents of my webpage using native code(Java).

Comment: it depends, if you are using an rss feed, or if you want to server petition, etc, what do you want to do? you need to explain better

Comment: no!! i am not using rss feed!!